# How can I access all columns of `i` when using .EACHI in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

as per `?data.table` when using `x[i,j]` where `i` is a `data.table`, columns of `i` can be accessed with `i.column` in `j`.
My question is how can I access ALL columns at once ?

Example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
DT <- data.table(A=c('a','a','b','b','c','c'),
                 B=rnorm(6L),
                 C=rnorm(6L),
                 key='A')
#   A           B           C
#1: a  0.82122120  0.61982575
#2: a  0.59390132 -0.05612874
#3: b  0.91897737 -0.15579551
#4: b  0.78213630 -1.47075238
#5: c  0.07456498 -0.47815006
#6: c -1.98935170  0.41794156

DT2 <- data.table(A=c('a','b','c'),
                  B=rnorm(3L),
                  C=rnorm(3L),
                  key='A')
#   A          B           C
#1: a  1.3586796 -0.05380504
#2: b -0.1027877 -1.37705956
#3: c  0.3876716 -0.41499456
```

Now say I want to multiply the column `B` of `DT` by the number `B` of `DT2` for each matching value of column `A`.
That is to say

```
0.82122120 * 1.3586796
0.59390132 * 1.3586796
...
```

I can do the following, but only because I know the columns are called `B` and `C`, and because I an patient enough to write all columns.

How could I do a similar thing with 100 columns for instance ?

```
DT[DT2,{print(as.matrix(.SD) %*% diag(c(i.B,i.C)))},by=.EACHI]
          [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 1.1157764 -0.033349750
[2,] 0.8069216  0.003020009
            [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -0.09445960 0.2145397
[2,] -0.08039401 2.0253136
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.02890673  0.1984297
[2,] -0.77121518 -0.1734435
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, there seem to be no special symbols like `x.SD` or `i.SD` to specify all columns (except the ones used in `by = ...`.

However, `mget()` can be used as a workaround which returns the expected results:

```
DT2_cols <- paste0("i.", setdiff(names(DT2), key(DT2)))
DT[DT2,{print(as.matrix(.SD) %*% diag(mget(DT2_cols)))},by=.EACHI]
```

> ```
>            [,1]        [,2]
> [1,]  0.3891785 -0.02190195
> [2,] -0.1140867 -0.03317559
>           [,1]         [,2]
> [1,]  1.850667 -0.009322052
> [2,] -3.533068  0.004944318
>            [,1]      [,2]
> [1,]  0.3706735 1.4268738
> [2,] -0.9229703 0.3679482
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: A,B,C
> ```

(Note that the numbers differ from OP's because using `set.seed(1L)` I do get different `DT` and `DT2` than posted by the OP.)

#### Edit: Feature request on GitHub

I just noticed that this feature already has been requested [on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/935).

Comment: yes I got that, I'll open a FR, I think it could be useful

Comment: Yep, that could be useful. Please, post link to FR. Thanks.