# how to speed up cross-column calculation in grouped data frame

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

--- Crossposting from [rstudio community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/group-max-performance/27852) for potential solutions outside of `tidyverse`.

The basic situation is that the calculations are independent between groups, but each group need to be fed some arguments calculated from itself. The trivial example is to find the index of the first element that's less than half of the column maxima.  The only twist is that one column `X` need to use maxima calculated through the others `A, B, C`.

I have a solution using `group_map` (similar to `do`) for my question on [grouped calculation](https://community.rstudio.com/t/summarise-at-for-grouped-data-apply-the-same-functions-but-different-arguments-to-columns/27392/8)). But the performance does not appear to be optimal.  It seems that `summarise_at` takes much longer when used with `group_map` (compared to timings w/o it)

```r
library(tidyverse)

times <- 1e5
cols <- 4
df3 <- as.data.frame(x = matrix(rnorm(times * cols, mean = 5), ncol = cols)) %>% 
   rename(A = V1, B = V2, C = V3, X = V4)

df3 <- cbind(grp = rep(seq_len(1e3), each = 100), df3) %>% 
   group_by(grp)

system.time(
  df3 %>% 
    group_map(~
    { 
      all_max <- summarise_at(., vars(A:C), max) %>% mutate(X = rowMeans(.))
      map2_df(., all_max, ~match(TRUE, .x < 0.5 * .y))
    }
    )
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    3.87    0.00    3.98

system.time(
  df3 %>% summarise_at(vars(A:C), max) %>% mutate(X = rowMeans(.))
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.02    0.00    0.01

system.time(
  df3 %>% summarise_at(vars(A:X), ~match(TRUE, . < 0.5 * max(.)))
)  
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.25    0.02    0.26
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Any idea to improve the performance?   It seems that most functions are column based and I have not yet find a solution to do this simple task efficiently.

Comment: maybe you would like to describe your problem instead of posting your solution? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The question is about the performance of the solution.  I will edit to clarify.

Comment: i don't really understand what you're trying to do with your code, can you please add some more exposition? The three snippets you provide all give different output.

Comment: Also, without a `set.seed`, it's especially difficult to reverse engineer what you're trying to do

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Sorry, the first one gives the results I want.  The second and third is just to check the time for the operation.  I wanted to demonstrate that `summarise` was much slower when used with `grooup_map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell this accomplishes the same as your code in less than half a second on my machine:

```
library(data.table)
DT = as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(times * cols, mean = 5), times, cols))
setnames(DT, c('A', 'B', 'C', 'X'))
DT[ , grp := rep(seq_len(1e3), each = 100)]

setkey(DT, grp)

DT[DT[ , lapply(.SD, max), keyby = grp, .SDcols = !'X'
       ][ , X := Reduce(`+`, .SD)/ncol(.SD), .SDcols = !'grp'], {
  i.A; i.B; i.C; i.X
  lapply(names(.SD), function(j) 
    which.max(eval(as.name(j)) < .5 * eval(as.name(paste0('i.', j)))))
}, on = 'grp', by = .EACHI, .SDcols = !'grp']
#        grp V1 V2 V3 V4
#    1:    1  3 30  1  4
#    2:    2  6 15  4 10
#    3:    3  2  5  7  2
#    4:    4  8 16  5  8
#    5:    5 10  3  1  7
#   ---                 
#  996:  996 11  5  3 13
#  997:  997  3  3  3 11
#  998:  998 14 21  2 10
#  999:  999 18  2  1 41
# 1000: 1000  8  7  3  3
```

Essentially, you are creating a look-up table of the relevant caps and joining back.

You could separate this by writing:

```
lookup = 
  DT[ , lapply(.SD, max), keyby = grp, .SDcols = !'X'
     ][ , X := Reduce(`+`, .SD)/ncol(.SD), .SDcols = !'grp']
DT[lookup, on = 'grp', {
  i.A; i.B; i.C; i.X
  lapply(names(.SD), function(j) 
    which.max(eval(as.name(j)) < .5 * eval(as.name(paste0('i.', j)))))
}, by = .EACHI, .SDcols = !'grp']
```

Once it's separated, you also gain the flexibility of getting `get` (which in my experience is slower than `eval(as.name())`):

```
DT[lookup, on = 'grp', {
  lapply(names(.SD), function(j) 
    which.max(eval(as.name(j)) < .5 * get(paste0('i.', j))))
}, by = .EACHI, .SDcols = !'grp']
#        grp V1 V2 V3 V4
#    1:    1  1  5 26  3
#    2:    2  6  7  3  4
#    3:    3  2  6  1 13
#    4:    4  5  2 12  5
#    5:    5  9 12  2  4
#   ---                 
#  996:  996  1  3  4  1
#  997:  997  1  6  3 13
#  998:  998 10 13  9  8
#  999:  999  2  4 13  4
# 1000: 1000  7 30 19 14
```

Comment: It's indeed much faster.  It looks that the join and the calculation are done together, which I think is not possible with `dplyr`.   Can you help to explain the calculation in the braces?  What does the first line `i.A; i.B; i.C; i.X` do?

Comment: @Dong that is simply a hack to force those variables to be populated within the `j` environment -- if we exclude this, the next line will error saying `i.A` can't be found. Also, the calculation can easily be separated; see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.   Do you have a way to have all variables (except the grouping ones) in `j` environment?  My actual use case have indeterminate number of columns.

Comment: @Dong see edit; I bootstrapped on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46946694/3576984) related answer; I know this is clunky, in fact, making this more smooth is the subject of some outstanding feature requests: [#935](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/935) and [#1180](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1180)

Comment: Thx.  It is indeed tough for me to understand and may not be a general solution.  For example, if my function is more complex and need to be defined separately, how could I pass the vector (here `eval(as.name(j))`) and the number (here `get(paste0('i.', j))`) to the function.  It seems that the function would need to be able to search the environment from which it get called.